# Calculating % of total with a Grouped Case statement

Tags: sql, t-sql, case

So I have a CASE statement that I've Grouped.  But, I was also trying to calculate the percentage of the total for each Grouped CASE result.  When I run the commands I made below, it gives

```
Region         Number  Percentage
West Coast     11675   0
Not West Coast 104620  0
```

I don't understand why 'Percentage' comes as '0'.

Here's the code, with the 'problem line' labeled.

```
With [Summed Region] AS
(

SELECT 
    [State Province],

    CASE [State Province]
    WHEN 'Oregon' THEN 'West Coast'
    WHEN 'Washington' THEN 'West Coast'
    WHEN 'California' THEN 'West Coast'
    ELSE 'Not West Coast'
    END AS 'Region'

FROM 
  [WideWorldImportersDW].[Dimension].[City]
)

SELECT 
    Region,
    count(Region) AS Number,
    ---THE PROBLEM LINE IS BELOW THIS---
    count(region)/(select count(*) FROM [WideWorldImportersDW].[Dimension].
    [City]) AS Percentage


FROM 
    [Summed Region]

GROUP BY
    Region
```

What's the problem with that line?  If I split out the two pieces, each returns the correct number.  But when I divide one by the other I get '0'.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called integer division.  So add a decimal somewhere:

```
SELECT Region, count(Region) AS Number,
       count(region) * 1.0 / (select count(*) FROM [WideWorldImportersDW].[Dimension].[City]) AS Percentage
FROM [Summed Region]
GROUP BY Region;
```

You don't need the subquery either, so use window functions:

```
SELECT Region, count(*) AS Number,
       count(*) * 1.0 / sum(count(*)) over () AS Percentage
FROM [Summed Region]
GROUP BY Region;
```

Comment: Oh yeah...I think I've actually done that with a window function, just apparently combining CASE & GROUP reached the limits of my imagination. Thanks again!                                                                     For anyone else who comes across this - Overly-complicated, but one could also do `CAST(count(*) AS FLOAT)` to get over the whole dividing integers by integers thing, instead of multiplying by 1.0